# php counting issue using array_walk

Tags: php, arrays

I had something very different and was having issues with an `array_map` code I had written. I asked for help and someone was nice enough to suggest he code below. However it seems to have a couple of errors and since I didn't write it and am not as familiar with `array_walk` I could use some help getting it to work.

The issue - instead of providing me the actual counts of each object in the DB, it is counting the types instead. As an example, if Type_2 has a qty of 3, it is displaying as 1 since there is only one column with Type_2.

```
$bl_type = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Type FROM mytablenamehere");

$bl_type = [
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_0'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_1'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_1'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_1'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_2'],
];

$types = [
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_1'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_2'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_3'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_4'],
];

$counts = array_count_values(array_column($bl_type, 'Type'));
array_walk($types, function($item) use ($counts) {
    $item->Frequency = $counts[$item->Type] ?? 0;
});

echo '<table id="count"><tr>';
foreach($types as $item) {
    echo '<th>', $item->Type, '</th>';
}
echo '</tr><tr>';
foreach($types as $item) {
    echo '<td>', $item->Frequency, '</td>';
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

An example output of the array:

> array(4) {
> [0]=> object(stdClass)#2657 (1) { ["Type"]=> string(8) "Type_0" }
> [1]=> object(stdClass)#2658 (1) { ["Type"]=> string(7) "Type_1" }
> [2]=> object(stdClass)#2659 (1) { ["Type"]=> string(7) "Type_1" }
> [3]=> object(stdClass)#2660 (1) { ["Type"]=> string(7) "Type_1" }
> [4]=> object(stdClass)#2661 (1) { ["Type"]=> string(8) "Type_2" }

Comment: *The error is "unexpected?"* can you give the full error.  Also with the sample data, what would you expect the output to look like.

Comment: clarified . It is telling me the ? (question mark) is unexpcted

Comment: That suggests you're on an ancient version of PHP that doesn't have null-coalescing operator.

Comment: using PHP v 7. The error is coming out of DW since I cant see errors properly on the site so it might not be an issue in the wild but the counting problem certainly is not working on the site itself

Comment: And what's your question about this code? "A couple of errors" occur, so could you share them?

Comment: Thanks - from above - "The issue - instead of providing me the actual counts of each object in the DB, it is counting the types instead. As an example, if Type_2 has a qty of 3, it is displaying as 1 since there is only one column with Type_2."

Comment: What exactly is the problem? When I run the code from your question, I see expected counts.

Comment: @el_vanja - As an example, if Type_2 has a qty of 3, it is displaying as 1 since there is only one column with Type_2. I dont want to count the types, I need the count of each type and their qty.

Comment: I can see that in your question, but it's not clear. Where is this quantity? It's nowhere in the code.

Comment: Just added it and am assuming that the issue is the conflict that was not taken into account where $tb_type is duplicated. Is the first variable even needed? Doesnt seem to be doing anything

Comment: Is it possible that you are just not using the results from your query but a static array instead? Just remove the second assignment (`$bl_type = [...]`) then.

Comment: @ArSeN It is indeed, do I even need the second one that seems to be conflicting?

Comment: Sounds like having this in there is your whole problem, so just remove it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code shown, you are not using the data from your database at all:

```php
$bl_type = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Type FROM mytablenamehere");

$bl_type = [ // this assignment here is the problem
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_0'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_1'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_1'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_1'],
  (object)['Type' => 'Type_2'],
];
```

The second assignment `$bl_type = [...]` overwrites the contents of the variable `$bl_type` which was holding your database query results before. Therefore you will always only get the same results no matter what your database has stored.

Thus, just remove the second assignment and only keep this line:

```php
$bl_type = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT Type FROM mytablenamehere");
```